# How do you clone pages in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I'm a noob web developer and I'm wondering how I can clone some pages on Wordpress?

it would make life easier

Answer (score -1):

it's very simple Marconel, in the panel of pages of wordpress, we have the session of all the pages, inside it we see all the pages of our site when placing the mouse over one of them it will display some options such as: edit, quick edit, trash, see and "Duplicate Page" which will be exactly what you will use to clone a page, after that just edit the copy.